# Ember server doesn't run from synced folder OSX

Tags: node.js, macos, ember.js, vagrant, virtualbox

I faced a little bit confusing bug.
First of all, I have installed virtualbox and vagrant on OSX El Capitan and Linux Mint (2 different machines, macbook and desktop).
Then I created a [Vagrantfile](https://github.com/reillyethan/booker/blob/develop/Vagrantfile) for my [pet project](https://github.com/reillyethan/booker/). 
Then I tried to run `vagrant up` both on OSX and Mint.

Guess what? I didn't have any problems on Mint, but on OSX I've got one: it says I have no rsvp module installed while trying to `ember server`. It was strange, so I decided to delete node_modules folder, clear npm cache, reinstall node (different versions, such as 0.12, 0.13, 4.0) and different versions of npm. All of that experiments didn't help at all, so now I know for sure, that there is no problem in node itself (Also, I repeat, that Vagrantfile runs good on Mint).

Then, on OSX I tried to `vagrant ssh` and create a simple ember app manually and run it and it worked! So I'm pretty sure now, that my bug is in synced folder, but I don't know what's going on. Has anyone faced that? The owner of new ember app and synced folder is the same - vagrant. So I'm not sure now, that the issue is in rights on the folder.